# Fastest public transport from Vienna airport into city center?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, vienna, vie

I'm landing at Vienna airport on a Friday (work day) at 17h35 and I'm supposed to attend a meeting at 19h00 close to Stephansplatz in the 1st district. I have only carry-on luggage and an EU passport, flying in from a Schengen country, so I should be out shortly after 18h00.

What is the fastest public transport into the city center **taking into account it is rush hour**?

I'd like to be on-time to surprise my colleges at the meeting, who already started picking, like "*don't worry we'll wait for you*"

Comment: I'd go by taxi, but I'm worried about traffic jam

Comment: how about the CAT? how often does it run?

Comment: There's a CAT at 18:09 which arrives at Wien Mitte at 18:25. From there Stephansplatz is two stops away on the U3 underground line. You could make it for 19:00 with time to spare...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest would be to take an Intercity train from Vienna airport to Vienna Hbf. Cost is between 3 and 4 Euro (forgot the exact amount). There's a train something like every 15 minutes. Buy ticket from a machine, the line may be long.

There is also a CAT train, but it makes no sense if you have no/little luggage, because it takes the same time, while costing over 10 Euro.

At Vienna Hbf you jump into Metro (U1 line), and go three (or four?) stations north. to Stephansplatz, which is also on U1.

Don't use Google Maps for navigation, it seems not to know about U lines (only S lines).

Comment: Note: by 2017 September Google Maps have learned about U lines. Perhaps earlier but I am seeing it now. Nonetheless, Moovit is always a good choice.

Comment: Can it use them when calculating directions? It showed them on a map before, but they were always ignored when finding directions.

Comment: It includes them now.